# Excel - Pull data from a cell on a different sheet and hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I know how to pull data from a separate worksheet in excel by using the formula `=Sheet2!A2`. That pulls whatever data I have in the A2 cell from my Sheet2. But is there away to pull the data from that cell and hyperlink it to the cell by using a formula? I know you can manually link it but I'm trying to make my sheet as automated as possible. Anything helps, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a hyperlink? Just right-click, Hyperlink and select location in the same document.

Comment: @SJR Right, but is there a way to do it with a formula so its somewhat automated.

Comment: Yes you can do eg `=HYPERLINK(Sheet2!A1,Sheet2!A1)`

Comment: @SJR "Cannot open the specified file." error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=hyperlink("#"&address(row(sheet2!a2), column(sheet2!a2), 4, 1, "sheet2"), sheet2!a2)
```

You could also parse out the worksheet name with a long sub-formula based on the information function CELL.

```
=hyperlink("#"&address(row(sheet2!a2), column(sheet2!a2), 4, 1, mid(cell("filename", sheet2!a2), find("]", cell("filename", sheet2!a2))+1, 255)), sheet2!a2)
```

Due to the nature of the `CELL("filename", ...)` function, that will only return the worksheet name from a saved workbook. i.e. not an unsaved Book1.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the length of the URL's, sometimes =HYPERLINK still won't work due to character limit in cells.

This isn't my code but I can't remember the source:

```
Sub insertVeryLongHyperlinks()
Dim allCells As Range
Dim curCell As Range
Dim longHyperlink As String
Dim title As String

Set allCells = Range("A2:A2") '## Modify as needed

For Each curCell In allCells
    title = Cells(curCell.Row, "A").Value '## Modify row for visible text of hyperlink
    longHyperlink = curCell.Value

If Len(curCell) > 1 Then

    curCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=curCell.Offset(0, 1), _
                Address:=longHyperlink, _
                SubAddress:="", _
                ScreenTip:=title, _
                TextToDisplay:=title

Else
End If
Next

'MsgBox "Hyperlinks updated!"

End Sub
```

This will add a link into the cell to the right thanks to the offset, and will use the value in A2 as what you will see as the title. Using this you can create URL links that exceed the cell character limit.

Comment: Thank you for the response as well!